# How to change the title of java applet's message box?

Tags: java, swing, applet, message, joptionpane

Hey so i press on button and comes a message box, named "Message". How do i rename this title?

Searching for this but didn't find nowhere.

That's how i create a button and then activate it so message pops. Didn't paste whole code cause it's long, but that's pretty much it for this button.

```
private JButton readmeButton;

readmeButton = new JButton("Readme");
layout.setConstraints(readmeButton, constraints);
chartPanel.add(readmeButton);
readmeButton.addActionListener(this);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "lalala");
```

Comment: IIRC this can be passed as an argument to the message box. Post your code please.

Comment: private JButton readmeButton;

readmeButton = new JButton("Readme");
layout.setConstraints(readmeButton, constraints);
chartPanel.add(readmeButton);
readmeButton.addActionListener(this);

Comment: And then when i press that button:

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"whatever");

Comment: @user1880405 Please don't add code as comment because it is hard to read. Instead update your question using [[edit]] option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` has multiple overloads. One of them is [`showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent,
                                     Object message,
                                     String title,
                                     int messageType)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29).

You can use this:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "lalala", "title", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

other options for the last argument are `ERROR_MESSAGE`,
`INFORMATION_MESSAGE`,
`WARNING_MESSAGE`,
`QUESTION_MESSAGE`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "lalala","Readme",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

### [Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

On above link, there are many other options too. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello","Exit",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
```